# Trigger the ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am practicing on the angularjs website. In there, there is a searchbar, that executes a research on any change in the field, as long as the string length is superior to 2 characters.

Anyway. With Protractor, I use sendKeys to input a name, expecting the search to begin, but I can't get any results. Whereas when I do it manually, it works fine.
Here is more or less the piece of code I use to type in my research:

```
describe('Search Field', function(){

  browser.get('https://docs.angularjs.org/api');
  it('displays a frame with the results of the search', function(){
     var searchField = element(by.css('.search-query'));
     var searchResult= element(by.css('.search-results-container'));
     searchField.click();
     searchField.sendKeys('angular');

     //I use a wait function here to wait for the results
     browser.wait(function () {
             return searchResult.isDisplayed();
         },10000);         
     //Before doing anything else, I expect to see the results
     expect(searchResult.isPresent()).toBe(true);
     expect(searchResult.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

and the searchfield code is:

```
<input type="text" name="as_q" class="search-query ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" placeholder="Click or press / to search" ng-focus="focus=true" ng-blur="focus=false" ng-change="search(q)" ng-model="q" docs-search-input="" autocomplete="off" style="">
```

It seems that the `seach(q)` function is never executed with Protractor.

Do you have an idea of the cause behind this problem?

**edit**:

I managed to have the search result frame appear by using evaluate(). The code becomes:

```
describe('Search Field', function(){

  browser.get('https://docs.angularjs.org/api');
  it('displays a frame with the results of the search', function(){
     var searchField = element(by.css('.search-query'));
     var searchResult= element(by.css('.search-results-container'));
     searchField.click();
     topBanner.searchField.evaluate('search("angular")');

     //I use a wait function here to wait for the results
     browser.wait(function () {
             return searchResult.isDisplayed();
         },10000);         
     //Before doing anything else, I expect to see the results
     expect(searchResult.isPresent()).toBe(true);
     expect(searchResult.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

But the weird thing is that if I leave the sendkeys() command before the evaluate, then the search results won't appear.

So I consider this as a workaround, it enables me to work on the actual frame I wanted to reach. But I would like to know how to reach that frame without this trick.

Comment: Try searchField.blur() - maybe the field isn't loosing focus after entering the text. (just a thought)

Comment: I just tried to blur, or click on another element, no result though.

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you, but I did find this article, which I think might be able to get you on the right track: http://iswwwup.com/t/6484d98c7426/how-to-trigger-ng-change-in-directive-test-in-angularjs.html

Comment: I tried and failed. `sendKeys`, `actions()`, etc... doesn't trigger the change. Stumped.

Comment: SamHuckaby :  thanks, the article seems to say that Angular suppresses the "ng-change" trigger while composing characters. But the Angular documentation adds that it should trigger on leaving the form, or pressing the RETURN key (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange). I tried both, still no success.

Brine : thanks for trying !

Answer (score 0):

```
searchField.value('angular');
searchField.trigger('input');
```

after that you need

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: I tried those lines, as arguments to be evaluated (i want to keep the Jasmine syntax), but it doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by Jasmine syntax, Jasmine is JavaScript only. And your code seems incomplete. Where do you inject dependencies ?

Comment: I execute Protractor directly, it takes care of the dependencies. Also it wraps WebdriverJS, and uses some of Jasmine syntax in the code (describe, it...). That is why I can't use directly what you wrote. I have to encapsulate this. I tried with evaluate(..), but it does nothing. Now I try with browser.executeScript(...) but this does not recognize $scope. I am new to Javascript and Protractor, so forgive me if I use incorrect terms.